# Efficiently applying a function to a grouped pandas DataFrame in parallel

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I often need to apply a function to the groups of a very large `DataFrame` (of mixed data types) and would like to take advantage of multiple cores.

I can create an iterator from the groups and use the multiprocessing module, but it is not efficient because every group and the results of the function must be pickled for messaging between processes.

Is there any way to avoid the pickling or even avoid the copying of the `DataFrame` completely? It looks like the shared memory functions of the multiprocessing modules are limited to `numpy` arrays. Are there any other options?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to share arbitrary objects. I am wondering, if the pickling takes so much more time, than the gain through multiprocessing. Maybe you should look for a possibility to create bigger work-packages for each process to reduce the relative pickling time. Another possibility would be to use multiprocessing when you create the groups.

Comment: I do something like that but using UWSGI, Flask and preforking: I load the pandas dataframe into a process, fork it x times (making it a shared memory object) and then call those processes from another python process where I concat the results. atm I use JSON as a communication process, but this is coming (yet highly experimental still): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#msgpack-experimental

Comment: By the way, did you ever look at HDF5 with chunking? (HDF5 is not save for concurrent writing, but you can also save to separate files and in the end concatenate stuff)

Comment: this will be targeted for 0.14, see this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5751

Comment: @Jeff got pushed to 0.15 =(

Comment: you are welcome to do a pull-request if you would like. my PR is their.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the underlying Numpy arrays from your DataFrame ?

Answer (score 12):

From the comments above, it seems that this is planned for `pandas` some time (there's also an interesting-looking [`rosetta` project](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rosetta/0.2.4) which I just noticed).

However, until every parallel functionality is incorporated into `pandas`, I noticed that it's very easy to write efficient & non-memory-copying parallel augmentations to `pandas` directly using [`cython`](http://cython.org/) + [OpenMP](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openmp.org%2F&ei=HKpdVfyVJcj8ULXHgcAF&usg=AFQjCNGlD5aZM8ZP3Qx7WXT74Y7C54jLNQ&bvm=bv.93756505,d.d24) and C++.

Here's a short example of writing a parallel groupby-sum, whose use is something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import para_group_demo

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0], 'b': range(7)})
print para_group_demo.sum(df.a, df.b)
```

and output is:

```
     sum
key     
0      6
1      11
2      4
```

---

**Note** Doubtlessly, this simple example's functionality will eventually be part of `pandas`. Some things, however, will be more natural to parallelize in C++ for some time, and it's important to be aware of how easy it is to combine this into `pandas`.

---

To do this, I wrote a simple single-source-file extension whose code follows.

It starts with some imports and type definitions

```
from libc.stdint cimport int64_t, uint64_t
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map

cimport cython
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref, preincrement as inc
from cython.parallel import prange

import pandas as pd

ctypedef unordered_map[int64_t, uint64_t] counts_t
ctypedef unordered_map[int64_t, uint64_t].iterator counts_it_t
ctypedef vector[counts_t] counts_vec_t
```

The C++ `unordered_map` type is for summing by a single thread, and the `vector` is for summing by all threads.

Now to the function `sum`. It starts off with [typed memory views](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) for fast access:

```
def sum(crit, vals):
    cdef int64_t[:] crit_view = crit.values
    cdef int64_t[:] vals_view = vals.values
```

The function continues by dividing the semi-equally to the threads (here hardcoded to 4), and having each thread sum the entries in its range:

```
    cdef uint64_t num_threads = 4
    cdef uint64_t l = len(crit)
    cdef uint64_t s = l / num_threads + 1
    cdef uint64_t i, j, e
    cdef counts_vec_t counts
    counts = counts_vec_t(num_threads)
    counts.resize(num_threads)
    with cython.boundscheck(False):
        for i in prange(num_threads, nogil=True): 
            j = i * s
            e = j + s
            if e > l:
                e = l
            while j < e:
                counts[i][crit_view[j]] += vals_view[j]
                inc(j)
```

When the threads have completed, the function merges all the results (from the different ranges) into a single `unordered_map`:

```
    cdef counts_t total
    cdef counts_it_t it, e_it
    for i in range(num_threads):
        it = counts[i].begin()
        e_it = counts[i].end()
        while it != e_it:
            total[deref(it).first] += deref(it).second
            inc(it)
```

All that's left is to create a `DataFrame` and return the results:

```
    key, sum_ = [], []
    it = total.begin()
    e_it = total.end()
    while it != e_it:
        key.append(deref(it).first)
        sum_.append(deref(it).second)
        inc(it)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'key': key, 'sum': sum_})
    df.set_index('key', inplace=True)
    return df
```